# How do I publish my react app on github properly?

Tags: reactjs, github

[image]

I am trying to publish my react app on github.Here are the steps that I have followed.

1-I have installed git on my windows.

2- In Visual Studios terminal I have written git init

3-Then I have created a repository on github called "cartdemo"

4-In my package.json I have changed homepage, made the private false and added "deploy": "gh-pages -d build

5- Again in VS terminal I have written git add .

6-git commit -m "Go Live"

7-git remote add origin https://github.com/rahman23/cartdemo.git

8-git push

Note: Here you can see the files https://github.com/rahman23/cartdemo

However when I hit the link https://rahman23.github.io/cartdemo/ I get a page where it is written

cartdemo

This project was bootstrapped with Create React App.

Available Scripts

In the project directory, you can run:

npm start

Runs the app in the development mode.

Open http://localhost:3000 to view it in the browser.

The page will reload if you make edits.

You will also see any lint errors in the console.

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: https://medium.com/@_mariacheline/deploy-create-react-app-project-to-github-pages-2eb6deda5b89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 8, you need to tell git which repo and branch to push the project to.  Since you added an origin, you would...

```
git push origin master
```

Since the project has now been pushed, add this to your package.json file.
   `"homepage" : "http://rahman23.github.io/cartdemo"`
then run: 
    `yarn build` in the console, and try pushing it again...

Comment: Ok I did everythin from begining again and I have added "git push origin master" as well but I still dont get the app on page?

Comment: Check out the link sakoBu posted in his comment.  Looks like a good article to bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

First of all install gh-pages by runnung `npm install gh-pages --save-dev`  or `yarn  install gh-pages --save-dev` or `brew install gh-pages --save-dev`. Then open `package.json` file. Add these lines in the script

`"predeploy": "npm run build"  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"`

so that it looks like this;

`"scripts": { "start": "react-scripts start", "build": "react-scripts build", "test": "react-scripts test", "eject": "react-scripts eject", "predeploy": "npm run build", "deploy": "gh-pages -d build" }` ,

Then add this line at the "homepage": "https://github-user-name.github.io/repo-name", then create your build folder by running `npm run buid` or `yarn run build` or `brew run build` depending on the os you are using.

Then run `npm run deploy` or `yarn run deploy` or `brew run deploy`.

Go to github settings near the top of the bar

Make sure you select  the branch you want to deploy from the drop down.

Make sure you have can see gh-pages selected and click save or leave it if it's already been selected. then go to 'view deployment' and there you go. Hurray now you know react!